# Kinect Format for ColorImageFrame

Tags: c#, kinect

I've set the kinects ColorImageFormat to RgbResolution640x480Fps30, yet the total amount of bytes reported is width * height * channels(?) = 1228800 bytes.

Wouldn't the length normally be of 921600 bytes which would be 3 channels for each value of red blue and green?

I figured they might have an empty alpha channel, but when I set my stuff to take RGBA with the same amount of bytes the image is black. Set to RGB I get an image that's displaced, but I do get the feed.

I'd like to know if anyone has an idea of what's in the extra channel of the kinect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, it seems that the internal structure is infact BGRA, I've set the Alpha channel to a value of 255(By looping every fourth channel) for maximum opacity and I display it in BGR instead of RGB and now it's working as intended.

So yeah, not sure if this is a specific case, but if you set the format to RGB, look at the byte size to make sure you are dealing with the right representation.